# Define Co-Finite topology On Set of Real numbers.

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking if there exists a Co-finite topology on the set $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When one talks about "cofinite topology on the set of real numbers", it's usually **the** cofinite topology, not *a* cofinite topology. So it's not something you can really look for an example of. There is just one.

The cofinite topology is defined by the open sets being the "cofinite" sets: the sets with finite complement (along with the empty set, of course). So any set which consists of the entire real line with a finite number of points removed is open, and the empty set is open. Those are all the open sets.

Finite sets are closed, and the entire line is closed, and those are all the closed sets.

Comment: aren't Empty set and real line clopen? since the complement of real line is empty set (which is finite)?

Comment: Yes, they are. I even said as much in my answer.